# Redirect index.php to root without affecting other urls

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect index.php to my root folder with out affecting other pages. I have tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://example.com/ [NC,R]
```

This one worked solved the problem in conditions such as

`http://example.com/index.php` but when I visit a URL such as

`http://example.com/index.php?option=users`, it displays as

`http://example.com/?option=users` which should not happen.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html), you need to add this line before the `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
```

This makes sure that the rule is only applied if the query string is empty.